# Initialize Git in an Already Ignored Subdirectory

Tags: git

I have a subdirectory that I'd like to keep track separately from its parent.

```
parent/
  .gitignore
  child-1/    # I want to track this separately.
  child-2/
```

In `.gitignore` I already have `child-1/`, which correctly ignores the subdir. However, when I `cd child-1/`, *git* still considers `child-1` belongs to `parent`'s git (i.e. by typing `git status`).

Yes, I could go to `child-1/` and type `git init`. But, is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  But the subproject (`child-1` in this case) needs to exist as a separate, independent repository first; then you can import it as a submodule of your `parent` project.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming `child-1/` didn't need to be "connected" to `parent/`, _submodule_ would not be necessary, right?

Comment: If the `child-1` project has no relation to `parent`, don't put it in `parent`'s working copy; move it somewhere else.  If the `parent` project depends on `child-1` existing in a subdirectory, that's what submodules are for.

Comment: There's reasons that you may want the file structure organization without creating a submodule. For instance: a common set of tooling that can be maintained separately from an application (see [angus](https://github.com/nickjanssen/angus) as an example).